# Mac gcc/g++/clang++ compilers for programming in c++

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, clang++, g++4.8

I have a programming class that has a requirement for making the code successfully compile on gcc/g++ 4.8.x or clang++. I'm running mac OSX el capitan at the moment.

```
$ g++ --version
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr -- 
with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 7.3.0 (clang-703.0.31)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
```

This is the clang++ output:

```
$ clang++ --version
Apple LLVM version 7.3.0 (clang-703.0.31)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
```

Would this suffice for the requirements for my class? If not how would I go about updating them?

Thank you!

Comment: It says *"or clang++"* without specifying a version, and you certainly have clang++. (Note that you don't have g++. `g++` on your system seems to be a symlink (I assume) for `clang++`.)

Comment: What clang++ version is equivalent to g++ 4.8.x?

Comment: It shouldn't really matter. Just make sure you stick to C++11, rather than C++14 or C++17 which are not supported by that GCC version. You can assure this by passing `-std=c++11` to the compiler invocation.

Comment: So in g++ 4.8.x and clang++ (C++11) are there any main differences in how they compile (other than the error messages) or would they not have any major differences in output when compiling work for a class?

Comment: As long as both use the same C++ standard version and you stick to the standard, there are only rare edge cases in which they differ. You should not have any problem with that in class. As I said the C++ standard version can be explicitly specified with `-std=c++XX` where `XX` is the version. You should ask your instructor which version you are going to use.

Comment: Alright thank you so much!